# Cannot import org.apache.lucene

Tags: java, netbeans, import, lucene

I wanted to use [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html) library. I have downloaded it and added it as Zip file [project properties--> Libraries --> Add Jar/Folder]to my project. But I simply cannot import it. when i type in:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token;
```

it simply says package does not exist!

if i type

> import org.

it gives me some suggestions but no apache.

Netbeans works fine since i already imported guava.jar and using the google.common libraries.

Does it has anything to do with me adding a zip as the library? shall i do something extra after i added zip file? is there anywhere that i should check?

Comment: are you sure you downloaded the lucene library and not the server ? The default download button on the lucene website point to the lucen server.

Comment: this is the link that i have downloaded it from: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/java/4.8.0

Comment: that zip contains different lucenes jar files, you need to extract it and add core/lucene-core-4.8.0.jar + analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.8.0.jar as dependencies of your project

Comment: Thanks! it worked! 

Generally, was it wrong ,what i did?  I mean generally cant you just add the zip file assuming it adds all the jar file?

Comment: No you can't add a zip containing jars, you need to add jar individually, or use maven to manager your dependencies

Comment: Thanks alot! would you make it as an answer so i flag my question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you downloaded a zip containing several lucene jar files.

That zip contains different lucenes jar files, you need to extract it and add

- core/lucene-core-4.8.0.jar
- analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.8.0.jar

as dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to simply download the jar files and add them to your class path.

Note that importing only the Lucene Core jar would not work, as the Analyzers are in a separate jar named `lucene-analyzers-common-{version}.jar`.

At Maven Repository you can find the most recent versions of the [Analyzers jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common) and the [Core jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core).