# error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist

Tags: java, jar, lucene, tokenize

I am working with an NLP project and there's this Tokenizer.java file which when I execute, is giving multiple errors related to importing of lucene.analysis()

I checked if all the lucene jar files are present in the lib folder of the tokenizer. it turns out all the lucene files are present-
lucene-analyzers-common-5.2.0,
lucene-analyzers-kuromoji-5.4.0,
lucene-analyzers-smartcn-5.4.0,
lucene-core-5.4.0

tools\tokenizer\src\Tokenizer.java:24: error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;

Comment: Which editor tool you used ?eclipse ?

Comment: I use notepad++

Comment: have you read this answer ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/23571796/3514144

Comment: yes, I read that answer, i have both lucene-core and lucene-analyzers-common jar files added as dependencies to my project

Comment: I downloaded lucene again from https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/5.4.0/ and unzipped the file and added all the jar files individually, but still it is showing all the errors.

Comment: I have even tried setting the classpath for all the jar files, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: need to check your setup if is possible screenshare than may i help otherwise it's hard to understand where exactly you miss something

Comment: yeah sure, I am willing to screen share, just tell me how exactly should I do that. there's no such option on stack overflow for screen sharing.

Comment: can you tell me your apache.lucene version ? and show me the dependency?

Comment: its 5.4.0 and this is the link of the my project - https://github.com/shangjingbo1226/AutoPhrase

Comment: when I am running auto_phrase.sh, I get multiple import errors related to the lucene package and others in the Tokenizer.java file located in the tools folder

Comment: try with replacing https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/5.4.0

Comment: still the same, all the same errors again